# Is there any way to make a draft pull request using git bash?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-push

I want to make a draft pull request but when I execute the command `git push --set-upstream origin new-branch` I could only see normal pull request button at my repository. Even though I've all the permission to the repository. So is there any way to make a draft pull request using git bash ?

Comment: May we ask what your motivation is for wanting to create a "draft" pull request?  Ideally you should get all your code in working order before creating the pull request.

Comment: Actually my teammate want to test some code which I changed locally so I thought to make a draft pull request instead of normal one cause my code was not complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull requests are not a Git feature, which means you literally cannot make them with Git.

You make pull requests on *GitHub* using *GitHub* features.  As shown in the [introduction](https://github.blog/2019-02-14-introducing-draft-pull-requests/), you do this *on* GitHub using the clicky buttons there: having done your `git push origin`, you navigate to the correct page, start the process, then use the drop-down field to select the "draft" type of pull request.

Note that draft PRs are not available in all types of GitHub repository.  For details, see [the GitHub documentation on draft PRs](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-requests#draft-pull-requests).

Comment: So sorry for that as I am not a pro in Git. I thought there might be some way to make a draft PR as I don't know why can't I'm able to make a draft PR even after going through the link your shared of the documentation.

Comment: You're probably not using a public repository, nor a Team or Enterprise repository. If you have a private, but unpaid, repository, GitHub will not let you use various features. (They charge money for those features.)

Comment: Actually the repository owner has the subscription, I'm just the contributor to that. So is it the problem ?

Comment: Ah, probably so. I'm not up on all the fine details of GitHub's settings but I get the impression that if the repository owner is in that position, they probably need to list you as a member of their organization, to enable the feature.

Answer (score 1):

A pull request generally is created when some unit of work which is ready to be used has been completed.  In your case, you are sitting on some intermediate work, not yet ready to generate a pull request.  Therefore, I would just suggest that you commit your work and push your branch to the repository.  Most enterprise Git providers, such as BitBucket and GitHub, have features which would allow someone else to view a diff of your intermediate branch against some target branch.  Based on this diff, they may give you feedback.  All this can be done without creating a formal pull request.

Answer (score 0):

Update May 2022: [gh v2.10.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.10.0) comes with [PR 5570](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/5570):

> ### "Submit as draft" option for pr create
>
> `-d, --draft`: Mark pull request as a draft

---

2020: A possible workaround, entirely done from your local workstation, is to use:

- [gh (GitHub CLI)](https://cli.github.com/), to create a PR with [`gh pr create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create)
- convert that PR to a draft with the extension [`kyanny/gh-pr-draft`](https://github.com/kyanny/gh-pr-draft) (mentioned in [`cli/cli` issue 2271](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/2271)):

  ```
  gh pr-draft 1234
  ```
- Once you are ready, using [`gh pr ready`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_ready):

  ```
  gh pr ready 1234
  ```
- To convert a pull request to draft:

  ```
  gh pr ready 1234 --undo
  ```